# How to execute C#-Code after a new row in my MS SQL Table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I think the headline says it.

I try to execute an C#-Code after my MS SQL-Table get a new row.
Can anyone explain me how to do it, please?

I tried it with the C#-Class 'SqlDependency', but I think, this is not the right solution, because the C#-Code must always be restarted.

Should I try it with T-SQL and an SQL-Agent or something like that? Maybe I'm totally wrong with C #, I do not know and I really need your help!

I am pretty new here so please have a little patience with me :)

Greetings from Austria
Gazza

Comment: What have you tried?  If you place C# code after your Sql Data Client it will execute, could you be more clear?

Comment: I tried to monitor my MS-SQL-Table with the C#-Class 'SqlDependency'.
My idea was, that the SqlDependency-Class responds the change on my Table and consequently run the provided code

Comment: DO you want to do this all SQL server side? Or from the application?

Server side, you could compile a c#CLR and run this from a trigger. (I'm not a fan of triggers)

Answer (score 0):

**If you want a simple solution you can just try this:**

Use the `System.Data.SqlClient` to connect to your `Database`:

Then you can usr a Timer to run the "RowCountCheck" in a specific interval:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();      //using using System.Timers;
timer.Interval = 5000;          //Time for 1 interval in milliseconds
timer.AutoReset = true;         //Start again when elapsed
timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed; //Method called when timer elapsed

private int _lastRowCount;

private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   //Check row Count
   //Use your SqlClient here to get the rowCount
   

   if(_lastRowCount < currentRowCount)
   {
      //Row was added: Do your work here:
   }


  //Set the currentRowCount as _lastRowCount for the next check
   _lastRowCount = "yourValue";
}
```

Links:

> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp - How to get the RowCount from an SQL Table
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient(v=vs.110).aspx - SqlClient

Comment: That sounds logical to me. But, please excuse my silly question, can I to this all in C#?

Comment: @Gazza lets see if that helps you :D

Comment: I think this will work, but its not coupled very loosely, and could be problematic. What is this "service" was to stop? Or error out? Would it not be better to have a event raise from the row insert?

Comment: OK - perfect, thank you very much. I am understand this and it was no problem for me. 
Now, I have a additional question: How can I find out a column-value from the row, which has changed?
I hope you understand my question!